# Python How i can extract data with same class name in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull out data using BeautifulSoup library in python. I used zip and soup to extract.

My html data looks like this :

```
<li>

    <ul class="features">

        <li>Year: <strong>2016</strong></li>

        <li>Kilometers: <strong>81,000</strong></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="features">

        <li>Doors: <strong>2 door</strong></li>

        <li>Color: <strong>White</strong></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="features">

    </ul>

</li>
```

Here i want to get year,kilometers,doors,color in seperate variables. But when i run my code it getting together.

My code :

```
for title, price, date, features  in zip(soup.select('.listing-item .title'),
                            soup.select('.listing-item .price'),
                            soup.select('.listing-item .date'),
                            soup.select('.listing-item .features')):


    title = title.get_text().strip()
    price = price.get_text().strip()
    date = date.get_text().strip()
    features = features.get_text().strip()

    print(features)
```

Output :

```
Year: 2016
Kilometers: 81,000
Doors: 2 door
Color: White
```

How i can store the year,kilometers,doors,colors in seperate variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find element `li` which contains text and then find next strong tag.
Declare empty list and append.

**Code**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<li>

    <ul class="features">

        <li>Year: <strong>2016</strong></li>

        <li>Kilometers: <strong>81,000</strong></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="features">

        <li>Doors: <strong>2 door</strong></li>

        <li>Color: <strong>White</strong></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="features">

    </ul>

</li>
'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
Year=[]
KiloMeter=[]
Doors=[]
Color=[]
for year,km,dor,colr in zip(soup.select('ul.features li:contains("Year:")'),soup.select('ul.features li:contains("Kilometers:")'),soup.select('ul.features li:contains("Doors:")'),soup.select('ul.features li:contains("Color:")')):
    Year.append(year.find_next('strong').text)
    KiloMeter.append(km.find_next('strong').text)
    Doors.append(dor.find_next('strong').text)
    Color.append(colr.find_next('strong').text)

print(Year,KiloMeter,Doors,Color)
```

**Output**: list

```
['2016'] ['81,000'] ['2 door'] ['White']
```

Comment: i don't want to add it into array so i can do like kilometer = km.find_next('strong').text i'm i correct ?

Comment: If you don't use in array then if you have more than one elements the variable value will change and you will always get the last value of the element.

Comment: but i'm getting all years printed

Comment: Well if You want to print first value then do end of for loop. `Year=''.join(Year[:1])` print(Year) do the same for others

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from io import StringIO

data = """<li>
    <ul class="features">
        <li>Year: <strong>2016</strong></li>
        <li>Kilometers: <strong>81,000</strong></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="features">
        <li>Doors: <strong>2 door</strong></li>
        <li>Color: <strong>White</strong></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="features">
    </ul>
</li>"""

soup = bs(StringIO(data))
Year, Km, Doors, Color = list(map(lambda x: x.text.split(':')[1].strip(), soup.select('.features > li')))
print(Year, Km, Doors, Color)
```