# bs4: splitting text with same class - python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am web scraping for the first time, and ran into a problem: some classes have the same name.

This is the code:

```
testlink = 'https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi387906/wasa-volkoren'

r = requests.get(testlink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

products = (soup.findAll('dd', class_='product-info-definition-list_value__kspp6'))
```

And this is the output

```
[<dd class="product-info-definition-list_value__kspp6">13 g</dd>, <dd class="product-info-definition-list_value__kspp6">20</dd>, <dd class="product-info-definition-list_value__kspp6">Rogge, Glutenbevattende Granen</dd>, <dd class="product-info-definition-list_value__kspp6">Sesamzaad, Melk</dd>]
```

I need to get the 3rd class (Rogge, Glutenbevattende Granen)... I am using this link to test, and eventually want to scrape multiple pages of the website. Anyone any tips?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it always the third record? Can you get it using `products[2]` or something like that?

Comment: Try this Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057322/python-how-i-can-extract-data-with-same-class-name-in-beautifulsoup

Comment: `products = [x.getText() for x in soup.findAll('dd', class_='product-info-definition-list_value__kspp6')] 
print(products[2])`

Comment: @SergeyK Thank you so much! That works!! One more question... do you know what to do if it's not always the third record when scraping multiple pages instead of one?

Comment: @Eva I do not really understand what is the purpose, you need to display this text if it is found in the list of products?

Comment: @Eva, actually the url has no pagination option, if so, to get rid of any error, you can use `if else None` statement

Comment: @F.Hoque I need to get the allergy information. Initially, I though it would be the 3rd record on every page, so this was a test to see how I could display allergy information (so I could eventually loop through the pages in this URL: https://www.ah.nl/producten/pasta-rijst-en-wereldkeuken). Unfortunately, it's not always the third record...

Comment: may be somrthing like this - `if 'Rogge, Glutenbevattende Granen' in [product.getText() for product in soup.findAll('dd', class_='product-info-definition-list_value__kspp6')]:
  print('Attention, the product contains gluten!!')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all of dd tags with class value `product-info-definition-list_value__kspp6` and list slicing

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.ah.nl/producten/pasta-rijst-en-wereldkeuken?page={page}'
for page in range(1,11):
    req = requests.get(url.format(page=page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

    for link in soup.select('div[class="product-card-portrait_content__2xN-b"] a'):
        abs_url = 'https://www.ah.nl' + link.get('href')
        #print(abs_url)
        

        req2 = requests.get(abs_url)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(req2.content, 'html.parser')
        dd = [d.get_text() for d in soup2.select('dd[class="product-info-definition-list_value__kspp6"]')][2:-2]
        print(dd)
```